# Check Edit Differences

Tags: support

I edited a rather long question in SuperUser, and while I was given the `+2` reputation, my name was not listed as the one who edited it; someone else was.  I'm just curious as to what I edited incorrectly, or what the other user edited so that I can learn how to better edit.

Is there a way to see that?

Post in question:  [New computer build won't POST](https://superuser.com/questions/385380/new-computer-build-wont-post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows the most recent editor, not everyone who has ever edited the post. Somebody else edited the post again after you did, so they are shown as the most recent editor. You can see the full revision history by clicking on the "8 minutes ago" above the edited user, and [your edits show up there](https://superuser.com/posts/385380/revisions).

Comment: Ah, i see.  Great, thanks, that will help me understand better.